# how can I take the date out, put it in another field and leave the time?

Tags: sql, t-sql

how can I take the date out of `In time and Out time columns`, put it in another field and leave the time as HH:MM format?

[image]

**Desire results:(First line)**

Date: 2014-11-10

In: 07:28

Out: 17:29

Comment: Why would you put it in a text column and not in a `date` column?

Comment: because will be easy for me to ready it in a crystal reports @GordonLinoff, but Date is ok as well, so I need Time 2014-11-10, In 07:28 out 17:29

Comment: What if `IN` and `OUT` are on different dates?

Comment: it won't happen @Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
select 
    convert(date, [In Time]) as Date, 
    convert(time, [In Time]) as In, 
    convert(time, [Out Time]) as Out
```

(only works in sql server 2012 i believe.  What are you using?)

This link shows how to do it in SQL Server editions below 2012

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/06/sql-server-get-time-in-hourminute-format-from-a-datetime-get-date-part-only-from-datetime/

Comment: I marked your answer because you posted first and worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to handle this in your reporting tool.  But if you want to get it in SQL, 
`SELECT
  CAST (InTime as date), -- Gets you the date
  cast (InTime as Time),
  cast (OutTime as time)
....`